# Why does deconstructing array items lead to union types?

Tags: typescript

If I have:

```js
const pairs: [string, number][] = [['a', 1], ['b', 2]];

// Why is the type of this not just [string, number][]?
const x: (string | number)[][] = pairs
    .map(([s, n]) => [s, n * 2]);
```

Why do I end up with a union type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(For reference, this has been brought up in various issues, like [microsoft/TypeScript#16896](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16896) and [microsoft/TypeScript#25516](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25516).)

The compiler sees `[s, n*2]` and has to infer a type for it because your callback is not explicitly annotated.  Generally speaking, the compiler assumes that an array's contents might later be modified and that the order of the elements doesn't matter.  Here is some valid code that someone might write:

```
const myArray = [0, 1, "two", 3, "four"];
myArray[2] = 2;
myArray[3] = "three";
myArray.push(Math.random() < 0.5 ? 5 : "five");
console.log(myArray); // [0, 1, 2, "three", "four", 5] or something
```

That compiles with no error because the compiler infers the type of `myArray` as `Array<string | number>`.  If the compiler assumed that `myArray` were a tuple of type `readonly [number, number, string, number, string]`, then every line after that except for `console.log()` would be an error.

When it sees `[s, n*2]`, it infers the same type, `Array<string | number>`, for the same reason.  It doesn't know that after that gets returned you won't start modifying the array's contents.  It is likely forever beyond the abilities of the compiler to make the same inferences a human developer would. It uses heuristics which work for some cases, and don't work for others.

---

Luckily, the language lets us annotate and assert types explicitly when the compiler's inference heuristics get it wrong.  One of the easiest ways to do this is with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), introduced in TypeScript 3.4:

```
const x = pairs.map(([s, n]) => [s, n * 2] as const);
// const x: (readonly [string, number])[]
```

A `const` assertion essentially tells the compiler to infer the narrowest possible type it can; instead of assuming the array might be modified or reordered, it assumes that the contents of the array will never change, so you get a `readonly` tuple.  Does that meet your needs?  Or you could explicitly annotate the return type of the callback function:

```
const y = pairs.map(([s, n]): [string, number] => [s, n * 2]);
// const y: [string, number][]
```

That gives you the type you expected without `readonly`.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUEMEwLwwNoAMANDAIwkBEUA7iBSQMyUBmIArihQLoDcAsAChEqDAjwAmLjhjj+Q5Gkx4GU3FQAWKAKZaKc4YoQA6AA5sI6gBQBZdFHVGMYACYg4lgJQwAPDAJGAVhgAfhgggC4YCmYASwA3XQ85UEgQABstIzSQAHNLA1EkmAB6YvxiMhJxSnttXRZ2ThIAqRAUGAg3LXsYsBzBAYEU6BgTdBiUCEi8aBRenJIwNjgAIy0ULjxVfDwAcnRdklIuEj2Vw5kuXkHh2AAPaTGJiCM4dBNLSxnFri9sAD58BBFjAAFSXGDoCAwW5JQSlGHgEZ3SKWbToVxgNJYGZQOZ9RbLNYbDxbG5I2BYXBPSavd6fb4wMC-aazeaE1brVSAxlgMGXOECBG3GAIVl49lMolcskCGBAA)

Comment: A great help; your answer provides a full explanation, I was unaware of the `const` expression, which will be very useful